# scanf() expression being skipped

Tags: c, scanf

My problem is that the second `scanf(" %s", name);` doesn't work. It just doesn't wait for the user's input.

```
int main()    
{
    int ID = 0;
    char name[100];
    float CGPA = 0;

    printf("enter name\n");
    scanf(" %s", name);

    printf("enter float\n");
    scanf("%.2f", &ID);

    printf("enter name\n");
    scanf(" %s", name);

    system("PAUSE");    
}
```

Why does it skip this `scanf`?

Comment: Consistency is beautiful

Comment: possible duplicate of [when i try to scan more than 1 string in c programming there is something wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165873/when-i-try-to-scan-more-than-1-string-in-c-programming-there-is-something-wrong)

Comment: @user1193041 : Let me know if my answer has helped you. Then I would appreciate if you accept it if it has ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is at following line:

```
scanf("%.2f", &ID);
```

1. You have an error there, you meant `&CGPA`.
2. You don't need to specify precision here (`.2`), it's up to user. Simple `%f` will work fine.

It should look like this:

```
scanf("%f", &CPGA);
```

Hope this helps.